# Polar coordinate / circular layout for the whole facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a dataset with values 2 ordered discrete factors, with some corresponding continuous values. (random sample is generated below)

```
randomData = expand.grid(1:5, 1:100)    # The two discrete variables
colnames(randomData) = c("index1", "index2")

randomData$z = runif(nrow(randomData))   # The measured value 

ggplot(randomData, aes(x = 1, y = z)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(index1 ~ index2) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

I am trying to wrap the whole grid into circular / polar layout, such as the one displayed below, using the bar plots generated.

The first plot is the desired output (manipulated by a photo editing tool from the first facet plot).
The second plot is the output of this blog post: http://chrisladroue.com/2012/02/polar-histogram-pretty-and-useful/). However, it contains only a single "row".

[image] 
[image]

I cant figure out a way to do that. when I try to add `coord_polar()`, the bar plots themselves are affected and not the facet.

Comment: Have you read the entire blogpost on it? (Where you sourced the image). The author provides code on how to do it. http://chrisladroue.com/2012/02/polar-histogram-pretty-and-useful/

Comment: Yes Heroka. The main difference that I have two (and not one) discrete categories, each having a separate histogram.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output.. You want to have one plot for each value of index2 and in this you want to have 5 bars (one for each value of index1) arranged in a circle?

Comment: Hi konvas, I uploaded a new lot with the desired output. Hope that clarifies it

Comment: Why do you want this output? I can't help but think there are better way to visualize your data/convey your message.

Comment: The original data set is wide (ncol >> nrows) and will be color coded with a third discrete values. Circular layout will help fit/compress the plot. I definitely agree that the uploaded plots which use dummy data are meaningless, and could be designed better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can arrange facets in a circle, but you can cheat by changing your x and y variables and then using `coord_polar()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
d <- rbind(
    mutate(randomData, col = "dark"), 
    mutate(randomData, col = "blank", z = 1 - z)
) %>% arrange(d, index2, index1, col)

ggplot(d, aes(x = factor(index2), y = z)) + 
   geom_bar(aes(fill = col), stat = "identity", position = "stack") + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = c(blank = "white", dark = "black")) + 
   coord_polar() + 
   theme_minimal() + 
   guides(fill = FALSE)
```

[image]

You would have to adapt this quite a bit to fit your original data set but you get the idea - add rows for the values (1 - z) and use them to stack the bars

Comment: Thank you Konvas! That's what I was looking for :)

Comment: Very smart ! Maybe there is an easy way to map appropriate Y-axis labels, and to make the white bars transparent in order to see the panel grid. Then one could interprete size of bars. I will try to and will let you know if it works.